# Pass an object by reference to a method

Tags: c++, object, reference

I think the mistake i'm doing it's so stupid but i don't know what i'm doing wrong.
I have a class with static and non-static vars and some methods, all public. 
In my program i want to create an object and pass this object to a general method by reference.

The program doesn't compile and the compiler throws really weird error messages.

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "prueba::num", referenced
>   from:
>         _main in ccbRZYqe.o
>         metodoC(prueba*)    in ccbRZYqe.o
>         prueba::prueba()in ccbRZYqe.o
>         prueba::inicio()     in ccbRZYqe.o   "prueba::flag", referenced from:
>         metodoC(prueba*)    in ccbRZYqe.o
>         prueba::prueba()in ccbRZYqe.o
>         prueba::inicio()     in ccbRZYqe.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class prueba
{
    private:
    public:
        static bool flag;
        static int num;
        float complejo;

        // Metodos
        //--------------
        prueba()
        {
            flag = false;
            num = 0;
            complejo = 0.0; 
        }

        void inicio()
        {
            flag = true;
            num = 5;
            complejo = 3.2;
        }

        bool cambio()
        {
            flag++;
            num++;
            complejo++;
        }
};

bool metodoC(prueba* ensayo)
{
    cout << "-----------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "- flag: " << ensayo->flag << endl;
    cout << "- num: " << ensayo->num << endl;
    cout << "- Complejo: " << ensayo->complejo << endl;
    cout << "-----------------------------------------" << endl;

    return true;
}

//-----------------------------------
//      M   A   I   N
//-----------------------------------
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    prueba test;

    test.inicio();

    test.num += 2;
    test.complejo += 5.2;

    metodoC( &test );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define your static members. They are only declared.

```
class prueba {
  // as before
};
```

and in the **implementation file**:

```
bool prueba::flag=false;
int prueba::num=0;
```

Note that you shouldn't put the definitions in a header because you will get a definition of the statics for each translation unit. You need to put them in an implementation file that is then used to make a single object file that clients can build against.

Be careful though, each time you instantiate a new `prueba` object, you reset the static members in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks you for your clear answer. / Gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: @JorgeVegaSánchez de nada. I added one sentence about duplicated symbols, it could be important if you have more than one translation unit using your `prueba` class.

Answer (score 1):

static members in class should be declared inside the class but define outside the class

```
      `bool prueba::flag=false;`
       int prueba::num=0;`
```

add these after class and remove their defination from inside the constructor .

It will work fine for you

Comment: Actually, they need to be declared inside the class (as they are) and *defined* outside.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is because the num value in prueba is declared as static, hence accessing it by: test.num will not work, and this is why the value is undefined.

If you change that to prueba::num += 2; it should work ok, also add in the appropriate initializers:

```
bool prueba::flag = false;
int prueba::num = 0;
```

Comment: Both of those are perfectly valid ways of accessing the member.

Comment: @CD1212 It's not a required but improves understandability that members don't belong to any particular instance. The problem is the static members need to be defined in a translation unit.